# put LINQ code in sitecore code

Tags: linq, sitecore

I would to get "comment" by article ID . and i only can to get all comment in all article.
my plan is make LINQ code in my code

please check my code

```
var childrenss = new List<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item>();
foreach (var child in item.GetChildren())
{
    childrenss.Add((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)child);

}
```

any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is your `item`, the article? Or how do you identify your article? And are the comments the children from your article item? Can you please explain your structure of the content tree and what your current item in the code above is?

Comment: In this case I use video. I uploaded my videos to my media library. For the player I used flv player, and get the video url as a parameter to the player. Then I made a item called Video that in the code behind, I made a controller to made the comment. So the comment is the child of a video item. The flv player also put in the layout of the video item.

Answer (score 0):

Well it *looks* like you should be able to use:

```
using System.Linq;
...

var children = item.GetChildren().ToList();
```

Comment: item.GetChildren().ToList() will do just fine. GetChildren returns a ChildList object that implements IEnumerable<Item>

Comment: @RuudvanFalier: Thanks. Not sure why the OP has the cast in the current code then...

Comment: how about the LINQ statement? i have no idea to put your code.

Comment: @OganTobing: I have little idea what you mean. What LINQ statement? This code is using the `ToList` LINQ call. If you're asking about the "comment by article ID" part then you'll need to give us more information about the data model. We don't know what `item` is, or the children, or anything at the moment...

Comment: In this case I use video. I uploaded my videos to my media library. For the player I used flv player, and get the video url as a parameter to the player. Then I made a item called Video that in the code behind, I made a controller to made the comment. So the comment is the child of a video item. The flv player also put in the layout of the video item.

Comment: @OganTobing: None of that tells us what we'd need to know to help you, I'm afraid. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe our OP isn't very strong in English but for people working with Sitecore his comment makes more sense. I don't understand why he persists about using LINQ however...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm going to make a lot of assumptions here so if any of these are false and you need an explanation regarding any of the following let me know.

First of all I'm assuming your data in sitecore looks like this:

- Video Item

  - Comment 1
  - Comment 2
  - Comment 3
- Video Item 2

  - Comment 4
  - Comment 5

I also assume that you created a Sublayout that is meant to show the comments and that the Datasource of that Sublayout is a Video Item. (Incase this is not true you should consider it, integration of Sitecore DMS will later then be a lot easier)

In that case in your code behind of your sublayout there is no need to use any LINQ. You can simply use the following code:

```
public void Load_Page(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Sublayout sublayout = Parent as Sublayout;
    string datasource = sublayout.Datasource; // Contains Item GUID as string (if not using queries)
    Item datasourceItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(datasource));
    Repeater.Datasource = datasourceItem.GetChildren();
    Repeater.Databind();
}
```

So as you can see there's little to no reason at all to use any LINQ. For the sake of testing and argument you could demand that the Comment items are retrieved by using the Sitecore Index. To do that you can use the code from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847083/how-to-create-search-function-in-sitecore).